# How do I build a tree from a list of symbols?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tree

I am new to python.

I have a tree data structure that is defined like this (I didn't write it, it was provided):

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, name='root', children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        if children is not None:
            for child in children:
                self.add_child(child)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
    def add_child(self, node):
        assert isinstance(node, Tree)
        self.children.append(node)
```

The following function displays the tree:

```
def display_tree(root, indent=0):
    print(' ' * indent, root)
    if len(root.children) > 0:
        for child in root.children:
            display_tree(child, indent+4)
```

Now, I have a list of symbols, like this:

```
symbols = ['a', '[', 'b', '[', 'c', 'd', 'e', ']', 'f', '[', 'g', 'h', '[', 'i', ']', '1j', '[', 'k', 'l', ']', ']', 'm', ']']
```

I need to be able to get the tree like below:

```
 a
     b
         c
         d
         e
     f
         g
         h
             i
         j
             k
             l
     m
```

I found that the following lines of code gives me the result I need:

```
t = Tree('a',[Tree('b',[Tree('c'),
                        Tree('d'),
                        Tree('e')]),
              Tree('f',[Tree('g'),
                        Tree('h',[Tree('i')]),
                        Tree('j',[Tree('k'),
                                   Tree('l')])]),
              Tree('m')])
    
    display_tree(t)
```

So how do I convert the list of symbols into the form of 't' above, so that when I give the list as input to a function, I get the tree as the output?

My initial thought was to use a stack data structure, and keep pushing the symbols on to the stack until I encounter a ']', and then build a tree by popping the elements from the stack. But this does not preserve the order, and also I am not proficient enough in python to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a stack of recursion. Here is a recursive function to build the tree from those symbols:

```
def tree_from_symbols(symbols):
    it = iter(symbols)
    
    def recur(delimiter=None):
        nodes = []
        while True:
            symbol = next(it, None)
            if symbol == delimiter:
                return nodes
            if symbol == "[":
                for child in recur("]"):
                    nodes[-1].add_child(child)
            else:
                nodes.append(Tree(symbol))
    roots = recur()
    if len(roots) > 1:
        raise ValueError("The root is not unique")
    if len(roots) == 1:
        return roots[0]
```